# Rails - Why is OR not working here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to loop through the params and exclude certain params, so I used this loop:

```
params.each do |key, value|
  html += "#{key}: #{value}</br>" if key !='authenticity_token' && key != 'utf8'
end
```

Now, this works with && but when I tried to replace it with || :

```
html += "#{key}: #{value}</br>" if key !='authenticity_token' || key != 'utf8'
```

it didn't work. It makes more sense for it to work with OR because it loops through each key, value pair and if the key IS a_token OR key, then it should skip it. There can't be BOTH on the same line. I think I don't quite understand how Rails processes loops here and why the && condition works, could someone please explain it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
key !='authenticity_token' && key != 'utf8'
```

This will return `true` when key is neither `authenticity_token` nor `utf8`

whereas

```
key !='authenticity_token' || key != 'utf8'
```

This will return `true` for every key including `authenticity_token`, `utf8`
because

for `utf8` key `key !='authenticity_token'` will be `true`

abd for `authenticity_token` key `key !='utf8'` will be `true`

if you want to use || condition use following

```
!(key =='authenticity_token' || key == 'utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use OR the you should try something like this

```
if !(key =='authenticity_token' || key == 'utf8')
```

Its a Negation Logic

Comment: Or, if you prefer, `unless key == 'authenticity token' || key == 'utf8'`

Comment: using unless seems a more ruby-ist way to do this. Thanks.